Spring @LoadBalanced RestTemplate doesn't resolve inside interceptor
I have a custom RestTemplate that registers an interceptor:
  @Bean
  @LoadBalanced
  public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    var timeout = 15000;
    var clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
    clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);
    restTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(bearerTokenInterceptor));
    return restTemplate;
  }

The interceptor attempts to execute the request, and if the response is unauthorized, it fetches a new access token from the identity broker and try once again (to handle access token times out):
  @Override
  public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
    log.info("request get uri: {}", request.getURI());
    ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);

    if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED) {
      accessToken = keycloakService.fetchAccessToken();

      HttpRequest retryRequest = new HttpRequestWrapper(request) {
        @Override
        public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
          HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
          headers.putAll(super.getHeaders());
          headers.setBearerAuth(accessToken);
          return headers;
        }
      };
      response = execution.execute(retryRequest, body); // Retry the request
    }
    return response;
  }

The first execution works, with load balancer resolving service name to the correct host retrieved from service registry. The second one after retrieving a new access token however, doesn't seem to pass through load balancer, and sends a request to the raw service name with port 80. How do I fix this?

If the aim is to deal with access token timeout, it's better to check timeout locally with JwtDecoder before sending the request. That way, the request is only sent once, and load balancer is still working.
  @Override
  public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
    List<String> authorization = request.getHeaders().get("Authorization");
    if (authorization == null || jwtUtils.isExpired(authorization.getFirst().substring(7))) {
      accessToken = keycloakService.fetchAccessToken();
      request.getHeaders().setBearerAuth(accessToken);

    ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body); // Retry the request

    return response;
  }


  public boolean isExpired(String accessToken) {
    Jwt jwt = jwtDecoder.decode(accessToken);

    Instant expiration = jwt.getExpiresAt();
    return expiration.isBefore(Instant.now());
  }

